# How to create a 360 panorama image in Gatsby/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, panoramas, react-360

I am trying to understand how to create a basic 360 Panorama image in react/gatsbyjs where the user is able to infinite scroll the image horizontally. Here is the result I'm trying to achieve:

[sample site](https://www.concordbrentwood.com/hillsideeast/views.html#)

I could easily achieve this result with the help of a jquery plugin in normal html/css/js, however, I couldn't figure out how to properly do it the "react way". I've tried using react-vr, however, when I try to import all the needed modules from react-vr, the browser throws me the following error:

[image]

I'm still learning React,
So any pointers or suggestion would be much appreciated!

here's my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Pano } from 'react-vr'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import FooterMenu from '../../components/footer-menu/footer-menu'
import Content from '../../components/content-container/content'

import './upper.sass'

const UpperPage = () => {
  return (
    <Content>
      <div id="view-1" class="view-content">
        <Link to="/views" className="back-btn">
          &#8592; back
        </Link>
        <View>
          <Pano source={{ uri: '../../images/views/high.jpg' }} />
        </View>
      </div>
      <FooterMenu />
    </Content>
  )
}

export default UpperPage
```

Comment: I doubt this is the cause, but I noticed that you didn't wrap your uri in the 'asset' method.  Small change, but could be worth a shot.

See here for explanation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/static-assets.html#referencing-static-assets

See here for example:
https://github.com/facebook/react-360/blob/master/Examples/TourSample/index.vr.js#L117

Comment: Did you try recreate the `node_modules` by deleting it and then run `yarn install` or `npm install`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong I have tried that, it does not work.  It throws me the same error. I assume it has something to do with GatsbyJs and how i import react-vr? I'm not too sure

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it fixes the problem. It might have something to do with how my project is set up. I'm using GatsbyJs (a static site generator based on react. ) for building my project, not react-vr-cli. What I did was npm install react-vr and then import it into one of the page components, somehow this setup does not work. I'm not sure if i missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [`aframe-react`](https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-react) instead of [`react-360`](https://github.com/facebook/react-360) (rebranded react-vr). I simply integrated it with Gatsby project:

1. Follow [installation guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-react#installation) for `aframe-react` to add required dependencies to Gatsby project:

   ```sh
   npm install --save aframe aframe-react
   ```
2. Create Gatsby component/page (for example: `src/pages/virtual-reality.tsx`) with content below, and use it:

   ```
   import 'aframe';
   import 'aframe-particle-system-component';

   import React from 'react';
   import { Entity, Scene } from 'aframe-react';

   const VRScene: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
     return (
       <Scene>
         <Entity
           geometry={{ primitive: 'box' }}
           material={{ color: 'red' }}
           position={{ x: 0, y: 0, z: -5 }}
         />
         <Entity particle-system={{ preset: 'snow' }} />
         <Entity light={{ type: 'point' }} />
         <Entity gltf-model={{ src: 'virtualcity.gltf' }} />
         <Entity text={{ value: 'Hello, WebVR!' }} />
       </Scene>
     );
   };

   export default VRScene;
   ```
3. Run your Gatsby project by `npm start`:

   [image: ]]

#### [How is React 360 Different from A-Frame?](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/what-is.html#how-is-react-360-different-from-a-frame)

> A-Frame is a framework for building VR worlds using declarative HTML-like components. It has a rich collection of available components from a vibrant community, and is great for creating intricate 3D scenes that can be viewed in VR. We believe that React 360 serves a different use case optimized around applications that rely on user interfaces, or are event-driven in nature. Look through our examples to see the types of things you can easily build with React 360.
>
> Trying to figure out which framework is right for you? Here's a quick test. If your application is driven by user interaction, and has many 2D or 3D UI elements, React 360 will provide the tools you need. If your application consists of many 3D objects, or relies on complex effects like shaders and post-processing, you'll get better support from A-Frame. Either way, you'll be building great immersive experiences that are VR-ready!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the [legacy](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/from-react-vr.html) React VR project, but [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/setup.html) suggests that it's not intended to be included within an existing React component but instead built as its own project.

[This documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/integrate.html) offers two ways you can integrate a 360 project into an existing application, one of which is to use an iframe. To do this inside of Gatsby, you would set your React 360 project to build to a folder in the `static` folder of your Gatsby project (e.g: `your-gatsby-site/static/vr-experience/index.html`), and build/deploy it before you run `gatsby build`. This will copy your React 360 project over to your `public` folder on-build, making it available for HTTP requests.